# Error on MySQL trigger execution

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

So I have this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `onUpdatePlayerTracker` AFTER UPDATE ON `playtracker`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE players
SET deckplayedmost = (SELECT deckname 
                  FROM playTracker 
                  WHERE playerID =  old.playerID
                  AND  amount =  (SELECT max(amount)
                                    FROM playtracker
                                    WHERE playerID = old.playerID
                                    LIMIT 1))
,

deckplayedleast =(SELECT deckname 
                  FROM playTracker 
                  WHERE playerID =  old.playerID
                  AND  amount = (SELECT min(amount)
                                    FROM playtracker
                                    WHERE playerID = old.playerID
                                    LIMIT 1))
```

And when I try to update *playtracker*

```
PLAYTRACKER
PlayerID DeckName   Amount
    6     Space        1
    4     Space        0
    3     Space        1
    5     Space        2
    2     Space        1
    1     Space        3
    6     Sky          3
    5     Sky          1
    4     Sky          2
    2     Sky          0
    1     Sky          3
    3     Sky          1
    5     Ocean        3
    4     Ocean        3
    3     Ocean        0
    1     Ocean        8
    2     Ocean        4
    6     Ocean        2
    3     Mystic       2
    2     Mystic       3
    5     Mystic       2
    6     Mystic       4
    4     Mystic       1
    1     Mystic       1
    4     Forest       1
    6     Forest       5
    5     Forest       2
    3     Forest       1
    2     Forest       2
    1     Forest       3
    6     Desert       3
    5     Desert       4
    4     Desert       2
    3     Desert       1
    2     Desert       3
    1     Desert       2
```

Which should trigger the trigger, I am getting an error saying the update couldn't complete as the result contained more then one row. It doesn't specify where the multiple return is coming from. It should update players table below.

```
Players
PlayerID    PlayerName  DeckPlayedMost  DeckPlayedLeast     FavCardType     
1            Daniel     Ocean           Mystic              Duel
2            Gavin      Ocean           Mystic              Event
3            Patrick    Ocean           Mystic              Exchange
4            Joe        Ocean           Mystic              Attack
5            George     Ocean           Mystic              Event
6            Robert     Ocean           Mystic              Rares
```

This text is included as my post contains too much code and not enough of an explanation. Like I think I have provided enough explanation, I know it could be better, more detailed and whats not but I'm new to this. frankly I'm still surprised that people reply! I mean I'm rely grateful, learning can be such a difficult challenge, a real test of self and I am grateful to all of ye for yer help. Makes the stress of it all a little more manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get rid of that error but I did not look to see if your query is correct otherwise.

```
SET deckplayedmost = (SELECT deckname 
                  FROM playTracker 
                  WHERE playerID =  old.playerID
                  AND  amount =  (SELECT max(amount)
                                    FROM playtracker
                                    WHERE playerID = old.playerID
                                    LIMIT 1)
                  LIMIT 1)
,

deckplayedleast =(SELECT deckname 
                  FROM playTracker 
                  WHERE playerID =  old.playerID
                  AND  amount = (SELECT min(amount)
                                    FROM playtracker
                                    WHERE playerID = old.playerID
                                    LIMIT 1)
                  LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved it all right. I had another error in there too. Thanks for your help.